# I'm getting the error: petition of a member in something that it's not an structure or an enum in C

Tags: c, list, generics, void

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make a generic list in which I could put any data type inside the node by using a `void*` to it. This is the generic list and the structure I want to put inside of it.

```
typedef struct LIST{
  struct LIST *next;
  void *data;
} LIST;

struct person {
    char *name; 
    int age;
};
```

This is the function to assign the pointer

```
LIST *create_node(void *data, int size) {
    LIST *tmp;
    tmp = NULL;
    tmp = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    tmp->data = malloc(size);
    tmp->data = data;
    memcpy(tmp->data, data, sizeof(data));
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
```

This is the function where I call the `create_node` function

```
void test_list() {
     LIST *my_list;
     struct person *my_person;
     my_list = NULL;

     my_person = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
     strcpy(my_person->name, "PABLO");
     my_person->age = 23;
     my_list = create_node(my_person, sizeof(struct person));
     printf("%d \n", my_list->data->age);
}
```

The problem comes in the last line in which I get the error: "petition of the member age in something that is not an structure or an enum". How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: What is `LISTA`? If it's a misspelling of `LIST` then what is the member `sig`? Its not in the `LIST` declaration.

Comment: `void *` is an incomplete type, so you cannot dereference it. You're trying dereference `data` (`data->age` or `(*data).age`) which is `void *`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, my bad, i translated some names of the variables so that they could have more sense to you

Comment: `tmp->data = data;` in `create_node` will overwrite the pointer returned by malloc. Apart from the undefined memcpy call that this induces, your code will almost certainly die as soon as you start freeing data.

Comment: Also, `strcpy(my_person->name, "PABLO")` will fail: `my_person->name` hasn't been initialised, so will contain a random pointer. This line should could read `my_person->name = strdup("PABLO");` (if you want a fresh pointer for each name) or just `my_person->name = "PABLO";` if you are going to use constant strings everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `data` as a `void *`.  If you know for sure that it's really pointing at a `person`, then you'll need to cast:

```
((struct person *)my_list->data)->age
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would do slightly differently, but the specific error here is in this expression:

```
my_list->data->age
```

remember from your declaration of the LIST type that the type of `my_list->data` is `void *`.  *You* know that this particular `void *` actually points to a `struct person` -- but the compiler does not, and cannot know this, since these two functions might be in different files compiled at different times.

So, you need to explicitly tell the compiler that this `void *` should be treated as a `struct person *` using a *type cast*:

```
((struct person *)my_list->data)->age
```

Comment: Yes, my idea is that the client of the function, in this case the `test_list` function is the one that has to do all the type cast work. My generic function `create_node` is going to handle all the work with the list.

Comment: Right, but you're *not* typecasting in the client.  That change has to be made in the last line of `test_list`, so that the client knows what type to treat `my_list->data` as (since that field is declared as pointer to void).